# React Native FlatList horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Is it possible to initialize React Native Flatlist horizontal scroll to the right end. I have a list which contains different times for a day. If the time has past already I would like the view to be scrolled to the right end.

```
       <FlatList
        data={this.getData()}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderContent(item, index)}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.time}
        horizontal={true}
        scrollEnabled
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      />
```

Comment: See if this helps https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#scrolltoend

Answer (score 1):

You can set initial scroll index of flat list by indicating specific index.

```
<FlatList
        data={this.getData()}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderContent(item, index)}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.time}
        horizontal={true}
        scrollEnabled
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        initialScrollIndex={this.getData().length - 1} // specify last index
      />
```